# How can I make jar in linux?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

how can I make jar for my java files in linux?
I have this situation:
I have in directory src this stuff:

```
   Client.java  //source code
    GUI.java    // source code
    miglayout-lib.jar //external lib 
    icons // folder in which are 20 jpeg pictures
```

when I want to compile it I use

> `javac -cp "miglayout-lib.jar:." *.java`

when I want to run it I use

> `java -cp "miglayout.jar:." Klient`

//cause Klient is class with main. 
**How can I make some build file or script (something like make) which will make me one jar file with my application and I'will be able to run it?**

Thx.

Comment: Did you try Google at first? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jar.html

Comment: @Midhat what?? Are you sure it's right link?

Comment: @user1097772 nevermind mate. I just cracked a joke. but do try the script I gave you to create a jar!

Comment: @Midhat I hope you have enough fun :/

Comment: There's a good answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125639/how-to-create-a-jar-file-using-the-terminal

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use command line utility named `jar` e.g.

`jar cvf classes.jar .*.class`

Use online help of `jar` for more info.

Since `jar` is a part of JDK it is cross platform, so it works on all operating systems. 
But it is very low level. You can use it as an exercise but in real life I'd recommend you to use one of popular build tools like ant, maven, buildr, gradle etc.

Comment: Also commons IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse provide building jar facilities

Comment: Thx, but on that machine i'll test and run it there is no ant installed :/
So I have to use some not tool dependable script :/

Comment: AlexR: Thanks it helped me to find right way. I made shell script and used this command  `jar` with some other options there.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 popular options for Java:

- Ant: http://ant.apache.org/ -> With Ant, you have to write your own build script that will call the [compile task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) and the [jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html). See [Writing a simple buildfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html) to get started
- Maven: http://maven.apache.org/download.html -> With Maven, you are more declaring some attributes of your build and everything is handled by Maven itself. See [Getting Started](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html) for more info there. If you want to just double-click on the jar to start it, you need to make the jar executable. See [Make The Jar Executable](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html) on how to do that with Maven.

Comment: +1, Thankyou for these wonderful links, saved me the pain to search things on GOOGLE.