# Creating jar from command prompt giving error

Tags: java, jar

I have tried the example as the same as written as answer from this link'[How to create a .jar file using the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125639/how-to-create-a-jar-file-using-the-terminal)' to create a jar file from command prompt. But I  am getting an error `'no main manifest attribute , in Helloworld.jar'`. What will be the problem? Please help.I done the same as explained in that method.

Comment: How are you building your project ? Is it maven ?

Comment: @wrongAnswer I am building my project from simple way no IDEs used!!

Comment: I strongly suspect you *haven't* done exactly the same thing. What does your manifest file look like before jarring? If you extract the jar file, what does the manifest from it look like?

Comment: @JonSkeet manifest file looks like Main-Class: HelloWorld

Comment: Does the class HelloWorld exist in the source you're compiling?

Comment: And has that successfully been included in the jar file? (This is all information that should be in your question.)

Comment: @C.Ross it is in the same directory

Comment: @JonSkeet my question is when I do the step 'java -jar HelloWorld.jar' I am getting 'no main manifest attribute , in Helloworld.jar', instead of printing my result

Comment: and the manifest file is ended by a new line? This is important.

Comment: We're *trying* to help, but you're not giving us the information that we've asked for.

Comment: try editing your question tell the procedure how you created the jar and necessary information like if it contains some package definition if it contains some other class definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using instead 'jar cfe HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld HelloWorld.class'  of 'jar cfm HelloWorld.jar Manifest.txt HelloWorld.class'. Thanks guys!!