# Can't create executable jar file with Terminal

Tags: java, jar, terminal

I try to create a simple executable jar file. My steps are:

Test.java

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Terminal:

```
javac Test.java
```

produces Test.class

Checking:

```
java Test  
Hello World
```

creating a manifest.mf file:

```
Main-Class: Test
```

Then

```
jar -cfmv Test.jar manifest.mf Test.class   
added manifest  
adding: Test.class(in = 413) (out= 287)(deflated 30%)
```

Finally

```
java -jar Test.jar  
no main manifest attribute, in Test.jar
```

I followed all the steps from Katanas answer here: [How to create a .jar file using the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125639/how-to-create-a-jar-file-using-the-terminal)

**Update:**

As adviced by ScaryWombat, I unzipped the jar file:

```
ls -alR  
.:  
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 3 infiniteZero infiniteZero 4096 May 28 02:25 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 infiniteZero infiniteZero 4096 May 28 02:26 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 infiniteZero infiniteZero 4096 May 28 02:19 META-INF
-rw-rw-r-- 1 infiniteZero infiniteZero  413 May 28 01:50 Test.class

./META-INF:
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 infiniteZero infiniteZero 4096 May 28 02:19 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 infiniteZero infiniteZero 4096 May 28 02:25 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 infiniteZero infiniteZero   94 May 28 02:19 MANIFEST.MF

cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Test.class
Created-By: 9-internal (Oracle Corporation)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18562277/2310289

Comment: Thanks, I've added a new line, but that does not help, i.e. I get the same error message.

Comment: a jar file is basically a zip file so rename it and open it in your favourite zip client.  Is the contents as expected?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I updated the post with the information. I think it looks like it's supposed to be. 
Furthermore I tried switching the extension but it still throws the same error.

Comment: On further inspectation, it seems to add a .class to the Manifest Entry

Comment: Yeah, that's quite strange. If what is above is true, then it looks like the MANIFEST.MF file is inside META-INF inside the .jar, where it should be. The weirdest part is that this works for me. I'll keep on looking... Make absolutely sure that newline is there, when I tried this I got the same result as you before I added the newline. It might not be saving or something.

Comment: Nevermind. That was still there from my other attempts. It just says "Test" now, but I still get the same error. Could it be something about my java version or anything?

Comment: Clarify, what just says "Test" now?

Comment: When I unpack the jar file and look in the manifest file, there is the entry Main-Class: Test

Comment: Alright, that's weird. If there's no newline after that then I'm not sure what's going on; I am fairly certain however that it isn't your java version. I don't think the requirements for a jar manifest have changed at all in a while. There's probably a small mistake that you're overlooking because it seems so ridiculous, that's what I've learned is usually the problem with things like this :)

Comment: better check that the `jar` command and `javac` command are both java9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an empty line at the end of your manifest, recompile and run. And the manifest you are feeding the compiler hast to be in UTF-8

or:

- open the jar location in total commander
- click jar file and press Ctrl + PageDown
- META-INF -> right click manifest and hit edit
- add an empty line at the end of your manifest
- save/exit and run java -jar Test.jar

Comment: OP states adding a newline at the end of the manifest file doesn't help.

Comment: OK but he didn't try to fix it directly in the jar and rerun

Comment: I don't think downvoting this is necessary, he had other solutions as well as adding a newline.