# External Jar file import with property

Tags: java, jar

I am new to java development and need a suggestion.

I need to import some external jar file into eclipse to use the methods. However that external file has a property file from which it gets the configuration. Now I am able to include the external jar file into my project but cannot include the properties file. it is throwing error when I add property file in the external file library.

Could you please suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please add the code where you use the properties file (if you are using it directly in your code) and the stacktrace to a depth of about 4-5 method calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the property file to the class path, and keep it externally. Many libraries use property files to configure themselves. For example, [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/faq.html#configFileLocation) and [log4j](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_configuration.htm) do.

`java -cp propertyfile`

Use the -cp parameter when launching the program. Refer to the documentation of the external library you are using for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Can I add that external property file in my java program, like I am doing for the external jar and export it as single jar with no dependency on additional file? I wanted to have a single JAR file that includes my program and external jar/config.

Comment: Could you please let me know the steps how to do that? Any screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10132818/4425643 you can always post a new question if you have trouble creating the jar file. personally I was using ant but no one uses that anymore