# How do I create a jar file via the command line?

Tags: java, java-16

Lets say I have these .java files:

- MainClass.java
- 2ndClass.java
- BarClass.java
- FooClass.java

Then I turn them into .class files:

- MainClass.class
- 2ndClass.class
- BarClass.class
- FooClass.class

How would I make it a jar file, and have MainClass.class be the first to be loaded?

Comment: You would not. You would first compile your .java files to .class files. You would then create a [manifest file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html). Finally you would jar the class files and specify the manifest file. Documentation is at the link provided.

Comment: I would suggest you to check Maven or Gradle, that will help you like nothing else

Comment: Please, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10132818/8370915). It might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observing what Elliott said about class files, you can create (in recent versions of jar) the manifest implicitly with

```
jar cvfe m.jar MainClass *.class
```

That assumes that MainClass is in the default package ('no package') (not good practice). That will then run with

```
java -jar m.jar
```